# ASP.NET MVC 5 - model value not getting passed correctly

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing a Web Application in MVC 5 - also using Web API with Kendo UI Grid to display data.  When loading the grid of car data it is based on a customer id that will be set on the model.

The markup for the Kendo UI Grid is in a Partial_View.

So in my MVC controller I have something like below:

```
model.CustId = "12345"; //just hard coded - will possibly come from query string or set somewhere else
return PartialView(_CarDetails, model);
```

Within my _CarDetails partial view the Kendo Grid code is as below.  I have also set a @Html.HiddenFor in the partial view for the CustId

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CustId)

                    //other setting up off Kendo UI Grid removed for Brevity
                      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                          .Ajax()
                         .Read(read => read.Url("api/Car/GetDetails").Type(HttpVerbs.Get).Data("GetCustId"))
                      )
                      )
            </div>
```

So on the Page which loads the Partial view in my Document.Ready I have a js fucntion which GetCustId - it is as below:

```
    function GetCustId() {
        alert('@Model.CustId');
        return { custId: '@Model.CustId' };
    }
```

alerting it returns blank and then if I seta breakpoint on my GetDetails method in webapi controller the custId field is null - if I hard code this to some value in my js function it gets passed fine but is there something incorrect in how I have wired it up to get the value from the model?

**UPDATE**

Web API method signature is as below:

```
   public DataSourceResult GetDetails([ModelBinder(typeof(ModelBinders.DataSourceRequestModelBinder))] DataSourceRequest request, string custId)
        {
            //this is another method in web api controller that calls services to get details and then maps the responses to View Model
            return GetCarDetailsByCustId(custId).ToDataSourceResult(request);
        }
```

Note I also updated the WebAPIconfig.cs file to inlucde {action} in the path as below:

```
      config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: What is the signature of the action within your controller for this?

Comment: @DavidShorthose - updated the question to include this

Comment: Post the markup where your adding the partial view into your main view

Comment: Rather than setting the value from the model what happens if you access the hidden for value via jquery? Eg $("#CustId").val() in your script

Comment: That is usually the way I would set values. Glad everything is working for you now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need the hidden field or js when the Model is already bound to the view. You should be able to just:

```
.Read(read => read.Url("api/Car/GetDetails").Type(HttpVerbs.Get).Data((string)model.CustId ))
```